# The elegant way to permit parameters by current user's role in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, pundit

My application has 3 roles: `:admin, :manager, :editor` and allows all of them to create products. But these users do not have the same permitted params.

```
:admin => params.require(:product).permit(:a, :b, :c, :d)
:manager => params.require(:product).permit(:a, :c, :d)
:editor => params.require(:product).permit(:b, :d)
```

I don't like to delete the keys because the logic is very complex and it's hard to read. I'm looking the way define the logic by action and role.

How can I permit the params by their role? What is the best way to do it? Is there any way like Pundit with authorization?

Thank you so much.

*Note: **[:a, :b, :c, :d]** is **dynamically** generated by checking policies using Pundit. Is there any extension for Pundit?*

Comment: Please add the `model`, `controller`, `view` code.

Comment: @JunanChakma I've just updated the description. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually create module `ParamsSanitizer` inside `app/services`.

And in the controller, I call like this: `ParamsSanitizer::Products.sanitize(params, current_user)`

All logics will be define inside these classes.

Comment: Thanks Doe, It's nice

Answer (score 1):

Set attributes to the constant based on their role.

```
ADMIN_ATTRIBUTES = [:a, :b, :c, :d]
MANAGER_ATTRIBUTES = [:a, :c, :d]
EDITOR_ATTRIBUTES = [:b, :d]
```

Then you can add three method for permitting params and call them based current user role.

```
def admin_params
  params.require(:product).permit(ADMIN_ATTRIBUTES)
end

def manager_params
  params.require(:product).permit(MANAGER_ATTRIBUTES)
end

def editor_params
  params.require(:product).permit(ADITOR_ATTRIBUTES)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, This is just for action `create`, the permitted params in action `update` is not as same as `create`. I have to create 3 more methods? :(

Comment: Why permitted params for `update` is different? it is totally different or just less permitted attributes then `create`'s permitted attributes?

Comment: Because of business logic :(. Permitted params are based on product's status, so it could be totally different

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you can do something like

```
def product_params
  case current_user.role
  when :admin
    params.require(:product).permit(:a, :b, :c, :d)
  when :manager
    params.require(:product).permit(:a, :c, :d)
  when :editor
    params.require(:product).permit(:b, :d)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, This is just for action `create`, the permitted params in action `update` is not as same as `create`. I have to add 3 more cases? :(